# Excel como comparar 4 critérios iguais numa tabela

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma tabela de características de jogadores.

Preciso de uma fórmula que verifique [VERDADE/FALSO] se **todas as características foram repetidas**

A tabela está contida no intervalo a seguir: **$R$3:$X$2004**
O intervalo de critérios é: **$S$3:$V$2004**

OBS: Vou usar apenas como formatação condicional
Tenho a fórmula que funciona para 2 critérios conforme demonstrado abaixo:
=E($S4<>"";$T4<>"";SOMARPRODUTO(--($S4&$T4=$S$4:$S$154&$T$4:$T$154))>1)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: SE(E( NÃO RESOLVE? , QUE PROJETO É ESSE? :)